# Trying to make array from file

Tags: java, arrays, file, printing

I am trying to make every line in a .txt file I have made in a program into each box in an array. The reason I want to do this is so that I can search for a word in each line in my file, and then print the entire line. The .txt file is formatted like this:
bird, sex, location, date
for when an observation of a bird has been made. The first thing I want to do is to be able to search for a bird and then get the entire line printed, and in another method I want to be able to do the same thing but searching for location. 
Currently I have something horrendous which does not work at all, and I could really use some help.

```
  void fugleType () {

System.out.println("Find observation by bird");

    List "fugler.txt" lines = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fugler.txt"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
String[] array = lines.toArray();
 }
```

}
`

Comment: What is this line of code supposed to do: `List "fugler.txt" lines = new ArrayList<String>();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors there and at the end you are trying to convert the array list to an array of strings.  Here is some code that works, minus the conversion to an array, which I will discuss shortly.

```
public void fugleType () 
    {
        System.out.println("Find observation by bird");
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try 
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fugler.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

IF you really need to convert this to an array of Strings you will have to loop over the Array list and add each element to an array of strings.  It is pretty simple, let me know if you want to see that code.  Howerver, you already have an arraylist against which you can perform your search operation.  Why not just use that?

Comment: Hmmm... Good idea. I just don't know how to search from an arraylist though. Not that good at this stuff yet. Have got to do some brute practicing, but must deliver this particular code in two hours so I suppose I will have to find something else then :P

Comment: Use a for loop to loop over the array list.  Each element is a string.  Perform your search on the string and if you get a hit, print the string.  Would you like to see the code?

Comment: It did help me, but managed another solution with some fewer lines of code which almost does it, some tweaks and I hope I'm there.